# Transitioning to OpenJDK/OpenJFX [Multi-Module Maven Project]

Tags: maven, gradle, javafx, java

I'm trying to migrate away from Java SE and it's JDK - to OpenJDK/OpenJFX, but am confused about the correct steps to get from Point A to Point B:

**Point A (current state):** I use IntelliJ IDEA CE on Windows 7, 64-bit to develop a multi-module project Maven project. This includes a parent, client and server module (3 total). My project currently relies on JavaFX (not OpenJFX).

**Point B (desired state):** I want to remove all reference to Oracle's JDK and JavaFX from my project and rely fully on OpenJDK/OpenJFX. My goal is to eventually license out the use of my application for a profit so this seems to be the best way to avoid an Oracle fee.

My options seems to be (1) build OpenJDK myself from [sources](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild) or (2) use a pre-built binary like the one offered [by Red Hat](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/overview/). Building it myself seems to avoid the ambiguous Red Hat terms [discussed here.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13235849) To confuse me further, JetBrains offer their own [Windows x64 OpenJDK builds](https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/openjdk8-windows-x64#files), I don't see if these should be used somehow.

I understand OpenJDK doesn't come with JavaFX so I need to build JavaFX from source regardless, as [described here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX#BuildingOpenJFX-Gradle) but it says I must have Gradle, not mentioning Maven.

This leaves me with 2 interrelated questions:

1. Do I really have to migrate from Maven to Gradle just to build the OpenJDK/OpenJFX? Can I use both? Perhaps I can use Gradle to do the building, and then *use* these builds within my current Maven project? Please clarify.
2. I can't find any helpful tutorial detailing the process for a Windows/Maven project to migrate to using OpenJDK/OpenJFX. Can you offer a helpful resource given this context?

   I'm assuming using a binary will save time, but building it myself would grant me the most license freedom.

I'm not seeking legal advice or license interpretation - only the logical steps an itelligent developer would take to accomplish my goal.

Comment: I don't think you understand the relationship between a Java application and the Java runtime. "I want to remove all reference to Oracle's JDK and JavaFX from my project." What references are you referring to? Or perhaps, what do you mean by your "project"? The development cycle is that you write some source code, create some other resources (images, supporting files, etc etc), and compile the source code. Then you usually bundle the class files and resources into a jar file. That jar file doesn't contain the Java runtime, or any "references to it": you just use a Java runtime to execute it.

Comment: The class files you generate by compiling will contain information about which *version* of Java they were built against, so they won't run with an earlier version than that. But they don't "care" what implementation of that version they use.

Comment: By "project" I'm referring to the collection of .java files I've written, the `pom.xml` file(s) related to each module, the resources (.fxml, .css, .png). By "references" I mean I want to cut ties with Oracle's JDK, whatever that may entail. It may only require changing IntelliJ's default project to OpenJDK and nothing more(?) If a jar file doesn't contain a runtime, how do you ensure the application runs on the appropriate runtime for an end user? I assumed I'd build the OpenJDK, then build OpenJFX, and include the OpenJFX runtime(?) in my application which I'd distribute. :/

Comment: But the `.java` files are not part of your project. The `.class` files are. What "ties with Oracle's JDK"? There are no such ties between any of the resources you list and the JDK. That is kind of the whole point of "platform independence", which is one of the fundamental pillars of Java.

Comment: On a similar note, I am curious as to what specific Oracle license fees you are referring to. As I understand it, Oracle's Binary Code License (BCL) only requires a fee if [commercial features](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/) are distributed/used. If you know of anything else, I would certainly like to know.

Comment: I have *no clue* what you are asking here. Unless you are building a native or self-contained distribution that includes a Java runtime from within your IDE, you don't need to do anything at all. You are still going to build your (platform independent) jar file exactly the same way. If you *are* building such a distribution, you just need to specify the Java runtime to bundle with it at the time you bundle your jar file with the runtime, using whatever tool you are using for that. Obviously you obtain that runtime however you want, whether downloading it from oracle or building it yourself.

Comment: @Frelling, the Oracle BCL is confusing with its "general purpose" terms, and scared me off. [Here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/12/16/oracle_targets_java_users_non_compliance/)'s an interesting article. Reading the 147 comments makes me very skeptical of Oracle, and many of the suggestions point to OpenJDK. Thoughts?

Comment: Also, are you logging into SO under multiple accounts? If so, please account for this behavior.

Comment: @James_D, yeah I had two different Chrome windows open and one fresh logged into my other by mistake. This allows me to organize different questions, and ask non-related questions on different topics without having to wait 90 minutes. Addressing your points above, I'm confused what the alternative would be to : `self-contained distribution that includes a Java runtime from within your IDE`. How else would the appropriate runtime be available to the end user if not contained (bundled) in the distribution?

Comment: I'm assuming I build OpenJDK... and also build OpenJFX, the latter of which contains the appropriate JavaFX run-time? I can then either bundle this runtime with my app (like Launch4J) does, or some alternative ... you haven't mentioned Gradle or Maven though so I don't see where that fits into your comment. Perhaps this part `using whatever tool you are using`...

Comment: @CaseyB. The Java runtime is available because its part of the standard installation of almost every operating system. Traditionally, developers have just shipped a jar file. If you do want to build a self-contained application bundle (or native bundle, or whatever your particular tool calls it) then that is a separate step to building your Java application. You don't need Gradle or Maven or any specific build tools for any of this, though for complex builds (like OpenJDK etc) build scripts are often provided. But building OpenJDK is completely independent from building your application.

Comment: So anyway, your question really makes no sense. You don't "migrate an application from Oracle JDK to OpenJDK" and you don't build an application for a specific Java runtime (again, that is basically the whole point of Java).

Comment: @James_D Well, then how do I build OpenJFX, since the instructions found [here](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX#BuildingOpenJFX-Gradle) specifically state I need Gradle. For OpenJDK I can use [an available binary](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/blob/master/README.md) but not for OpenJFX. Conversely, for building my application the goal is to create an executable which end users can double-click, go through an installer, and then see a `.exe` and `.dll`s so they can interchange them. That's it! That's another matter. Thoughts?

Comment: @Nova, ty for the article link. I can see your concerns. It is no surprise that Oracle is trying the "bait & switch" that other FOSS products are using, though Oracle's approach appears more clandestine. Here, this is free, but if you want to use that, you have to pay, but we won’t warn you that you have to pay. However, this impacts the end user, not the developer. Java developers are exempt from Commercial Feature license fees for the purposes of designing, development and testing. Disclaimer: None of this should be construed as legal advice.

Comment: @Frelling, it just seems that OpenJDK/OpenJFX offers more protection due to the GPL + ClassPath Exception. My entire confusion is based around (1) What is required for my IDE/Project/Computer/Whatever to fully use OpenJDK now, instead of JDK. What must I physically DO? (2) The link above states I must use Gradle to build OpenJFX (not included in OpenJDK binary)... but I can't find any alternative methods that don't use Gradle. Thoughts?

Comment: "How do I build OpenJFX, since the intsructions found here specifically state I need Gradle". I would suggest you install Gradle and follow the instructions.

Comment: @James_D, that seems like an overly simplistic answer. Please see question (1) in my original post. I now have to abandon Maven and the months of work I've put into learning it just to adopt Gradle so I can build the OpenJDK/OpenJFX once? Seriously?

Comment: I don't get what you are failing to understand here. You build a Java application. Use whatever you like to do that (any or all of javac, Maven, IntelliJ, Eclipse, Gradle, etc etc etc.) The Java application needs a Java runtime to run. You get a Java runtime from somewhere. *This is a completely independent thing.* You do this however you need. (You download a binary from Oracle, or you build the OpenJDK using Gradle, or you write your own if you really want and have a few decades to spare.) Optionally, you use a tool like Launch4J or javafxpackager to bundle your app with a Java runtime.

Comment: Why do you think that anything I have said implies that you have to "abandon Maven"?

Comment: I think I learned the most from your most dumbed-down answer, thanks for your patience. I don't think _you_ implied it, but that I assumed I had to choose either Gradle **or** Maven, since I always see posts about "Migrating from Maven to Gradle" -- as if we couldn't have both, nor use one temporarily. So it sounds like I **can** use Gradle just temporarily to build OpenJFX, and then not use it again - resuming use of Maven as normal. You said `build the OpenJDK using Gradle` but I think you meant OpenJFX, since there is an executable binary available for the OpenJDK itself.

Comment: OpenJDK will contain the relevant runtime, which will function properly with OpenJFX which I build. I'll then bundle that runtime with my project. Is that correct?

Comment: Sure, if that's what you want to do. Depending on your audience, I would probably just ship a jar file, tbh.

Comment: Why not bundle the runtime? Wouldn't that be more of a guarantee the recipient (customer) always has the appropriate runtime, instead of an outdated version? I don't see why you wouldn't. Plus, some of my dependencies are LGPL which require dynamically linked libraries, but I'm assuming these can be extracted out upon installation, so that users can interchange them. Feel free to ignore that point since off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to Gradle, you are only using it to build OpenJFX. It does not imply that you need to convert your Maven project to Gradle. Once you have overlaid OpenJFX onto your OpenJDK installation (see [Overlay - JDK 8](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX#BuildingOpenJFX-Overlay-JDK8)), your project should resolve all JFX references as before.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm off to the races now